# JQuery stringify not working

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring

Simply, I'm trying to parse a List of composite objects passed from Spring controller via ModelAndView object as the following

Spring part

```
ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("my view");
List<ActionHistory> histories = myService.getListData();
view.addObject("histories", histories);
return view;
```

In Jquery i tried couple of alternatives, first used the below line to construct JSON from List:

```
var list = JSON.stringify('${histories}');
console.log(histories);
```

the console is returning

> "[com.companyname.projectname.domains.ActionHistory@48126327]"
>
> **TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a**

I also tried from jquery-json by including "jquery.json.min.js" as a suggestion from this topic discussed but getting the same error above [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

```
var histories = $.toJSON('${histories}');
console.log(histories);
```

Comment: can u try this `var list = JSON.stringify('histories');
console.log(histories);`

Comment: if you mean to log the list before parsing it is returning (just as coming from the controller) [com.sbm.muras.domains.ActionHistory@64b4ac3b]

Comment: set your data to a hashmap and set this hasmap reference to the json object ref and send this to the js where you can just stringify

Comment: could you please explain what is the issue on list and why it should be working for MAP and not for list ?.

Comment: you have to print json string. javascript runs in browser long after your spring has completed it's job

Comment: @charlietfl that is the log of the object from java contains a list of three objects [ActionHistory [historyId=26, user=com.sbm.muras.domains.User@70419fe7], ActionHistory [historyId=25, user=com.sbm.muras.domains.User@5c9fd05e], ActionHistory [historyId=32, user=com.sbm.muras.domains.User@5c9fd05e]]

Comment: javascript and java run in different environments at different times. You have to serialize that data on server so javascript can read it in browser

Answer (score 0):

Check you contentType in ajax function it should be.

```
contentType: "application/json"
```

Also your Spring controller which is handling this mvc call should configure be configired with

```
produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
```

e.g. something like

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/getList", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```